# Mysql erro 1054 Unknown column

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Estou fazendo uma SQL que conta quantos nomes na tabela começam com uma letra qualquer porem está sendo retornado um erro:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'A' in 'where clause'

Para a seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author WHERE name LIKE 'A%';
```

Excutando diretamente no console do MySQL funciona perfeitamente porem ao utilizar em PDO é retornado o erro 1054.

```
$count = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author WHERE name LIKE \'' . $consulta->letter . '%\'';
echo $count; //Resultado : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author WHERE name LIKE 'A%'
$stmt = $conn->prepare($count);
```

Obs: Estou usando `PDO` e `Mysql`.

Comment: @JorgeB. Amabas as forma não funcionaram

Comment: Estranho porque pego resultado do `echo` e colo no console e funciona

Comment: Faz `echo "::$count::";` e põe aqui o resultado.

Comment: @JorgeB. ::SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author WHERE name LIKE 'A%'::

Comment: Não estou mesmo a ver...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o problema ocorre por causa do sinal `%`, que não pode estar aí. Experimente utilizar `bindParam`, assim:

```
$letter = $consulta->letter . "%"

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author WHERE name LIKE :letter');
$stmt->bindParam(':letter', $letter, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Gerou o seguinte erro: `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference`

Comment: Mudei para: `"$consulta->letter%"` e não funcionou

Comment: Desculpe, o segundo parâmetro deve ser uma variável, capaz de ser passado por referência. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Se trocar por bindValue() deve funcionar.

Comment: Utilizando sua resposata consegui chegar ao funcionamento pleno, creio que o erro seja a presença do `%` dentro da string que será prepara pelo PDO, pois já utilizei concatenações dentro da string que será preparada sem problemas (concatenei clausulas LIMIT)

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference` este erro me deixou bem intrigado pois já fiz da seguinte forma: `$stmt->bindParam(':description',$logMessage->mensagem,PDO::PARAM_INT);` e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Acontece que esse argumento precisa ser uma referência de uma variável. Note que antes eu tinha feito `$name . "%"`, que não é uma variável e sim uma concatenação, então não tem como existir uma referência nisto. No caso de `$logMessage->mensagem`, é possível.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria assim e funcionaria aqui:

```
$count = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author WHERE name LIKE '{$consulta->letter}%'";
```

Comment: Não funciona, ele testou.

Comment: bem estranho. algo nas configurações internas do php+pdo, será?

Answer (score 1):

> 1054 Unknown column '**nome da coluna**' in **local/clásula**

Esse erro ocorre geralmente quando a coluna não existe, foi digitada errada, faltou aspas em um valor que acabou sendo interpretado como uma coluna ou no pior caso a tabela acabou-se corrompendo.

O ideal é usar prepared statement e deixar coringa (`%` ou `_`) de fora a instrução sql e passar ele somente na hora de fazer o bind.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author WHERE name LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute(array('A%'));
```

[Coringas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
% - Qualquer caracter em qualquer quantidade.
_ - Um único caracter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema e segui a resposta dada pelo usuário "bigwebguy" aqui nesse link: [Getting raw SQL query string from PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210564/getting-raw-sql-query-string-from-pdo-prepared-statements)

Assim é possível identificar qual a query e parâmetros estão sendo executados.
Em meu caso foi necessário o uso de crase `` para que funcionasse.

```
$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array("\` name\`", '=', "joao"));

/**
 * Replaces any parameter placeholders in a query with the value of that
 * parameter. Useful for debugging. Assumes anonymous parameters from 
 * $params are are in the same order as specified in $query
 *
 * @param string $query The sql query with parameter placeholders
 * @param array $params The array of substitution parameters
 * @return string The interpolated query
 */
public static function interpolateQuery($query, $params) {
    $keys = array();

    # build a regular expression for each parameter
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($key)) {
            $keys[] = '/:'.$key.'/';
        } else {
            $keys[] = '/[?]/';
        }
    }

    $query = preg_replace($keys, $params, $query, 1, $count);

    #trigger_error('replaced '.$count.' keys');

    return $query;
}
```